# Upgrading Ethernet ports on Buffalo TS5800D

Tags: nas, upgrade

I recently picked up a Buffalo TS5800D NAS system from my workplace since they were decommissioning it and I was in the market for a NAS for my home network. I started watching some videos on YouTube about the software and I pulled up the user manual from Buffalo's website to start getting familiar with the machine before I go and plug it into my network and start configuring it. What I noticed is that the machine's two ethernet ports are limited to 1G transfer speeds and my entire home network is 2.5G. Since I intend to use the NAS primarily for media storage 1G can be limiting when looking at a file transfer of 20 to 50GB video files to/from the NAS. So, naturally my thought was, upgrade the ethernet ports to 2.5 or faster. I started googling and looking on YouTube to find videos, blog posts, or articles on the subject but came up rather short. Most of the results that came up on that search were the same things that I was already looking at for initial setup and familiarization.

Given the apparent lack of material on this subject I think I already know the answer, but I wanted to ask here as a last resort before I accept that this NAS will just be limited to 1G speeds out of the back and it was basically free so I don't have any room to complain. Has anyone successfully managed to upgrade the ethernet ports on a TS5000 series NAS and if so, what did you have to do to have the firmware accept the upgraded hardware?

Comment: A) Wrong site, read our help pages and B) this is never going to happen, the NIC chip will be SMT'ed to the systemboard, same for the physical port, even then it's an Atom-based 8-year-old N2815 CPU with 4 lanes of PCIe, which is only good for 2GB/s for everything - disk controllers, NICs and everything else, your phone's probably more powereful. That said I ran a home NAS at 1Gbps for years, worked fine, even for streaming 4K videos.

Comment: That's what I kind of figured the answer would be. Thanks @Chopper3. Also, looking closer this site is much better suited to this type of question. I was focusing too closely on the fact that this was a network storage device and passed over SuperUser because I thought it wouldn't deal with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

While there's NASes that would let you upgrade to faster networking, there's a few elements here that make it difficult - firstly, and most obviously, there's nowhere to plug in a 2.5 or 10GBe PCIe card. The NICs are onboard and soldered in so you can't swap em out.

There *are* NASes with PCIe slots and optional expansion, but mostly on the higher end

In theory you could plug in a 2.5 gig USB adaptor to a USB 3 port- but I suspect the driver support wouldn't be there on the stock firmware, and as an EOL system its unlikely